# Wordpress wp-cron on https (SSL) site

Tags: wordpress

Have anyone has an issue with wp-cron not working on SSL site?

I'm using Crontrol plugin to manage and debug this issue and it doesn't seems like wp-cron is firing at all even when I manually start it by clicking "Run Now".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one issue may have been fixed in WordPress 4.0:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12609

I'm still on the lookout for others.